# Importing .xib file from objective C app to be used in Swift app

Tags: swift, xib

I need to use my existing objective C code in an app which I am developing in Swift. Is it allowed to import the existing .xib file from the objective C app and use it in my current Swift app?

Comment: From what I understand this is only about reusing XIBs.. not ObjC Classes

Comment: down voted because the question shows no research effort (you could just try it out ;) of course it is also in the docs)

Answer (score 0):

A XIB doesn't contain either ObjC or Swift but some proprietary Apple XML that describes the UI you built in Interfacebuilder

XIBs made in 'ObjC Apps' are therefore the same as in 'Swift Apps' and can happily be reused.

---

no bridging required since you aren't copying code but xibs
(note that classes could also be used without a problem if this isn't about XIBs only.)